# How does one have believe in God?

Tags: knowing-islam

My probleme is that i wnated to become a believer but not a believer who just believes without knowledge and certianity .And i dont know why even though i saw the signs in the universe like the fine tuned universe and i still didn't  become a believer so i realise that my mind is deluded and is not able to find the truth and has become irrational , as it is said in the quran that even if the disbelievers see the signs they deny and i am one of that,so how to come out of it and how to fix this irrationality of mind and i don't  know why i don't accept the signs

Comment: have you read quran?

Answer (score -1):

Read miracles of Qur'an and science. Don't think much about Allah(who you called God). Allah has forbidden people to think about him and advised to think about Allah's creature. Just believe that there is Allah. But don't think how is Allah, What is Allah, How Allah works etc. Just think of Allah's creature.

Intention of your making question is a great sign that you are going to be a believer. You will be a believer Insha'Allah.

Answer (score -1):

How does one evaluate evidence?

They inquire, gather information, reflect on the stuff (evidence, theories, hypothesis, stories, etc) and then at some point, pick a position.

Later, new information might come to light, and the cycle repeats until *you* the person inquiring is feeling somewhat secure about your revised position or existing position.

The Qur'an claims, in several places, over and over again, that there is *plenty* of evidence for the belief in God.

May God make your inquiry easy, productive, and ultimately, favourable to your destiny with God.

Answer (score -2):

if you believe that this universe is really beautiful

then you also have to believe that the universe does not appear by itself and there is a creator

Comment: well , even though sometimes i think that it is beautiful and i think that  "Something can never come from nothing " even after that i m a disbeliever and i am a hypocrite

Comment: @Sauedur if you believe that something cannot come from nothing (i.e. 0+0=1) then, you must believe that there is a creator. Something that always existed that created the universe. The universe as we know it (i.e. energy and matter cannot exist infinitely, this is logically impossible).